# Mounting a remote Linux folder in Windows 7

Tags: ftp, ssh, samba, sshfs

So I had this idea to mount a remote Linux folder from a VPS on my Windows 7 machine.
So far I have tried dokan SSHFS, it works, but it is damn slow and buggy and it doesn't allow to edit anything directly. Next I tried NetDrive, it was slightly better. but not impressing at all. And for some reason it seemed to work significantly faster over WebDAV than FTP. Lastly I tried Samba over VPN. It took 50 seconds or so to simply open a folder.
Is there some other solution? Is it a Windows problem?

Comment: Try `max protocol = SMB2` in Samba's configuration file. SMB2 should be *a little* faster.

Answer (score 1):

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com) for Mac and Windows, does a great job.
Personally nowadays I just try not to have such a workflow or go with WebDav.

Comment: -1 cause the software is not free.